# Ранжирование результатов поиска в SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Допустим, у меня есть таблица `news` с колонками `id(PK)`, `title`, `description`. Также есть некоторый поисковый запрос, например, `'самолет'`. Как мне написать запрос так, чтобы сначала найти все записи с совпадением в `title`, затем все с совпадением в `description`, исключая уже найденные, и вывести все именно в таком порядке? Что-то по типу `(SELECT * FROM news WHERE title LIKE '%самолет%') UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM news WHERE description LIKE '%самолет%')`, но без совпадений во второй части запроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM news 
WHERE title LIKE '%самолет%'
   or description LIKE '%самолет%'
order by title LIKE '%самолет%'
```

По оператору `like` вполне можно сортировать. (как обычно, я мог напутать порядок сортировки)

Comment: Скорее `order by title LIKE '%самолет%' desc`. Я всё время путаю asc и desc

Comment: Да, похоже на то.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct <перечислить все столбцы кроме sortOrder> from
(SELECT 1 AS sortOrder, news.* FROM news WHERE title LIKE '%самолет%'
UNION all
SELECT 2, news.* FROM news WHERE description LIKE '%самолет%'
) X
ORDER BY sortOrder
```